# jqGrid dataInit within 'edittype' => 'custom'

Tags: jqgrid

It seems that the dataInit function is not fired if the 'edittype' is 'custom'. Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. In case of custom editing you must define [custom_element](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom) function which is responsible for **all actions** during the creating of the element. So no additional calling of `dataInit` functions will be done: you should call it from your implementation of the [custom_element](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom) if it is needed.

Comment: save d my life, was banging my head against the wall on this